# How to use JarOutputStream to create a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar

How does one create a JAR file programmatically using `java.util.jar.JarOutputStream`? The JAR file produced by my program looks correct (it extracts fine) but when I try loading a library from it Java complains that it cannot find files which are clearly stored inside it. If I extract the JAR file and use Sun's `jar` command-line tool to re-compress it the resulting library works fine. In short, something is wrong with my JAR file.

Please explain how to create a JAR file programmatically, complete with a manifest file.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your current (non-working) solution

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It turns out that `JarOutputStream` has three undocumented quirks:

1. Directory names must end with a '/' slash.
2. Paths must use '/' slashes, not '\'
3. Entries may not begin with a '/' slash.

Here is the correct way to create a Jar file:

```
public void run() throws IOException {
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
    JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.jar"), manifest);
    add(new File("inputDirectory"), target);
    target.close();
}

private void add(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException {
    String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
    if (source.isDirectory()) {
        if (!name.endsWith("/")) {
            name += "/";
        }
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        target.closeEntry();
        for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles()) {
            add(nestedFile, target);
        }
    } else {
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source))) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int count = in.read(buffer);
                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                target.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            target.closeEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: these 'quirks' are actually part of the zip specification (jar files are just zip files with a manifest and a different extension).  I agree that it should be documented in the API docs, though - I suggest opening an issue (http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/)

Comment: More importantly, the API should prevent you from creating invalid ZIP/JAR files by throwing exceptions if you pass in the wrong type of slash or by converting them automatically. With respect to directories ending with a slash, it should definitely be documented since there is no way to correct it automatically. I filed a bug report but it hasn't been accepted yet.

Comment: Classic Sun/Oracle. Closed as "not a bug": http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6873352

Comment: FYI - Zip spec: http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT - search for "file name: (Variable)".

Comment: @Gili The api cannot "prevent" you from using the "wrong" slash; because, the "wrong" slash is a valid character in the file name.  Not all operating systems recognize "\" as a directory separator, and those that do not allow (no-directory including) files names of "he\he\he".

Comment: in this call `add(new File("inputDirectory"), target);` where should `inputDirectory` be pointing? project root, or something lower in the directory hierarchy?

Comment: @AlexAverbuch, if I recall correctly, it should be pointing to the project root.

Comment: This program result Strange output
$ ls
MyClass.class output.jar
using this program i have created jar output.jar
$ jar tf output.jar 
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/Users/aninath/Documents/workspace/interview/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp2/tmp/
/Users/aninath/Documents/workspace/interview/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp2/tmp/MyClass.class
/Users/aninath/Documents/workspace/interview/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp2/tmp/output.jar

Comment: @anish: post a separate question. Comments aren't appropriate for this kind a question.

Comment: In my jar there are the class files listed with the classdirectory as prefix followed by the package structure. Is it possible to just have the package structure inside the jar somehow?

Comment: @Gobliins You need to post a separate question. Comments aren't appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: @anish @Gobliins Yeah, it's not quite right - there's a fix: if you add a String param "parents", then change the `name` assignment to `(parents + source.getName()).replace("\\", "/")`, add `name` to the recursive `add` call, and make a wrapper function that loops through the children of the original File, on each calling `add("", nestedFile, target);`, it gives the right relative paths.  Sorry if that's confusing; I don't have enough room to post all of both methods here.

Comment: @Gili Those were comments saying that the solution had a bug.  Why is a comment not the appropriate place for that?

Comment: @Erhannis It's not a bug per-se because this isn't the focus of the question. The focus of this question is how to create a JAR file using `JarOutputStream` and the answer does that. The implementation assumes that you want to pass the entire source path into the JAR file but this is something that you can easily modify.

Comment: @Erhannis can you please post the answer that solves this relative path problem? I really need it.

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha I've now posted an edited version of the code.  Should show up below, but here's a direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59439786/513038

Answer (score 11):

There's another "quirk" to pay attention: All JarEntry's names should NOT begin with "/".

For example: The jar entry name for the manifest file is "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" and not "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".

The same rule should be followed for all jar entries.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment to the accepted answer because it doesn't answer the main question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so by request, here's Gili's code, modified to use relative paths rather than absolute ones.  (Replace "inputDirectory" with the directory of your choice.)  I just tested it, but if it doesn't work, lemme know.

```
   public void run() throws IOException
   {
      Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
      manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
      JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.jar"), manifest);
      File inputDirectory = new File("inputDirectory");
      for (File nestedFile : inputDirectory.listFiles())
         add("", nestedFile, target);
      target.close();
   }

   private void add(String parents, File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException
   {
      BufferedInputStream in = null;
      try
      {
         String name = (parents + source.getName()).replace("\\", "/");

         if (source.isDirectory())
         {
            if (!name.isEmpty())
            {
               if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                  name += "/";
               JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
               entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
               target.putNextEntry(entry);
               target.closeEntry();
            }
            for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles())
               add(name, nestedFile, target);
            return;
         }

         JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
         entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
         target.putNextEntry(entry);
         in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         while (true)
         {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
               break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
         }
         target.closeEntry();
      }
      finally
      {
         if (in != null)
            in.close();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this code:

```
public void write(File[] files, String comment) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH + FILE);
    JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(fos, manifest);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(jos);
    jos.setComment(comment);
    for (File f : files) {
        print("Writing file: " + f.toString());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        jos.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(f.getName()));
        int c;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(c);
        }
        br.close();
        bos.flush();
    }
    bos.close();
//  JarOutputStream jor = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(PATH + FILE), manifest);

}
```

`PATH` variable: path to JAR file

`FILE` variable: name and format

Comment: What does this add that the accepted answer does not already say?

Comment: The accepted answer use more code than my. I think, you don't want to write very much code when you can write a bit.

Comment: In all due fairness, your answer contains less code because it does less. The accepted answer contains code that massages the input to the format expected by JarOutputStream . Your code will fail silently if you run under Windows or if directory names do not end with a slash.

Comment: The accepted answer also includes the manifest and the top-level directory entry. (I agree it could be more terse, though.)

Comment: Getting ClassFormatError with this - using the accepted answer works though.

Comment: The streams will not be closed if an exception is thrown in-between. You must use try-finally or try-with-resources to guarantee that the streams will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This answer would solve the relative path problem.

```
private static void createJar(File source, JarOutputStream target) {
        createJar(source, source, target);
    }

    private static void createJar(File source, File baseDir, JarOutputStream target) {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        try {
            if (!source.exists()){
                throw new IOException("Source directory is empty");
            }
            if (source.isDirectory()) {
                // For Jar entries, all path separates should be '/'(OS independent)
                String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
                if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!name.endsWith("/")) {
                        name += "/";
                    }
                    JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                    entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                    target.putNextEntry(entry);
                    target.closeEntry();
                }
                for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles()) {
                    createJar(nestedFile, baseDir, target);
                }
                return;
            }

            String entryName = baseDir.toPath().relativize(source.toPath()).toFile().getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(entryName);
            entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
            target.putNextEntry(entry);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int count = in.read(buffer);
                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                target.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            target.closeEntry();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ignored);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code for creating a JAR file using the JarOutputStream:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CreateJarfile.htm

Comment: I'm already doing this. In fact, the example you referenced to fails to point out that one must explicitly putNextEntry() on directory names or invoke JarOutputStream.closeEntry(). Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Ah, OK.  It was a little hard to offer a better solution without seeing any code, so I just pointed you at that reference.  Glad you figured it out though.