# Create a jar file from the java code

Tags: java

i want to create a jar file from java program i looked at some examples [Java code to create a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977663/java-code-to-create-a-jar-file) but it didnt impressed me as this will not create the proper package structure my original command was

```
jar -cfv formBuilder.jar .\com\accenture\* .\com\wysiwyg\util\XmlUtil.class  .\com\wysiwyg\exception\ApplicationException.class .\com\wysiwyg\constants\*.class .\com\wysiwyg\util\FormBuilderUtill.class .\com\wysiwyg\util\SaveFormOnLocalUtil.class .\com\wysiwyg\logger\LogInfo.class  .\com\wysiwyg\factory\Validation.class
```

now i want to do the same using java code but without ant, and proper package structures should be created, is this feasible?

Comment: Oracle (Sun) doucument can't be more detailed. Go through: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/ More precisely, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: @Nishant - i know using it from command line but wanna do it from my java code

Comment: oh, in a glance, it is not clear that it is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java.util.jar package for this work.

Comment: The java.util.jar package has some very good uses.  This is not one of them.

Comment: yep, this is not right. Use Jar tool, it's messy but that's the way. Better use some smart tool like ANT or Maven.

Comment: is there any example for the same available ? couldnt get through API only things are not getting clear :(