# Libraries to create jar from a Java file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to write a program in Java, which would collect a specified set of files from the physical location and place them in a jar in a certain directory.

I know I can use `java.util.jar` package for this. The package is great for sure, but I was wondering if there are any third party libraries that anyone at SO has used which they could recommend.

TL;DR: pick up files, create jar by placing them in pre-defined directories, all at run time in a java file.

P.S: I did not find any similar references to this question, but if there are then please refer me. Also, the title might be misleading, but I didn't find better words to explain my problem.

EDIT 1: I am not in anyway saying `java.util.jar` is bad or incomplete. All I am asking is if anyone has used any alternative solutions!

EDIT 2: I am trying to create the jar from inside the java program. The jar can be pretty big (~500mb) too. Trying to jar media files as well. So simply put, I pick up various files from certain locations on my drive and try to create a jar file by placing them in standard locations.

Thanks,
Ivar

Comment: Can you explain what functionality you need that is missing in `java.util.jar`?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295233/create-a-jar-file-from-the-java-code) gives a few pointers (and the java.util.jar way does not seem to convince many!). It all comes down to using the jar tool, which you can always call from java (process.exec(...)).

Comment: @Miserable Variable: I am just looking for an easier alternative.

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, I am trying to create the jar from inside the java program. The jar can be pretty big (~500mb) too. Trying to jar media files as well. So simply put, I pick up various files from certain locations on my drive and try to create a jar file by placing them in standard locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the java.util.zip package.  Jars are just zip files with some extra stuff in 'em

Comment: that is something I completely ignored! That is a great suggestion. Thank you!!