# Java - edit(unpack/pack) external jar at runtime?

Tags: java, jar, runtime, compression

I am developing a program that automatically modifies a jar file with already obtained class files(I am modding Minecraft automatically, to be exact).  This would involve unpacking the jar into a folder, editing the files(just a simple use of the File class), and repacking the jar and deleting the temporary folder with the edited files.  So, how would I go about decompressing/recompressing the jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class (which inherits behavior from the [ZipFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class).

Comment: How can I use JarFile to compress a directory full of .class files to a jar file, and vice versa?  I can't find it in the docs......

Comment: Poke around a bit... There's also JarInputStrem, JarOutputStream, and the same for zip files. And this site called [stackoverflow where people ask questions just like that ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281229/how-to-use-jaroutputstream-to-create-a-jar-file)

Comment: Thanks, man!  I think "poking around", as you call it is really a skill as a dev that I need to develop further.  Checked!

Comment: @Flafla2 Oh, man, there's no *end* to the poking around, believe me! Probably one of the most important skills there is, though, IMO. Something I look for when hiring.