# How do you make a function similar to jar -uf in Java?

Tags: java, function, jar

Using the standard Java API (i.e. the user doesn't need the JDK to run it), how do you make a function similar to jar -uf in Java? I have an idea that it will use the Zip library, unzip the .jar file, change the contents, and then rezip it, but I'm a newbie at Java, so I cannot really make it. Could you give an example or a function?

Thanks!

Edit: I think I found the answer here: [How to use JarOutputStream to create a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281229/how-to-use-jaroutputstream-to-create-a-jar-file)
I'll see if it works.

Comment: May be util.zip API help you. Refer this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-frame.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. My question is if someone could make a function or an example because I'm not an expert in Java (just learning).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JarInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html), [JarOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarOutputStream.html), [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), and [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html). They are a part of the JDK, so external libraries are not required. Pay attention that unlike other streams these require you to care about current entry. You can find a lot of examples of how to use the java zip API.

Comment: Yes, I know about them, but I don't know how to do it. Can you give an example?