# Loading a class in a .jar file created programmatically

Tags: java, sablecc

Here's my goal:  Use SableCC to generate several parsers/lexers at runtime and load instances of them for parsing and lexing.

So I figured my steps would be:

1. Generate the `.java` files using SableCC.  I think I've done this, fine.
2. Compile the `.java` file to `.class` files.  I did this using `JavaCompiler`.  I think this worked fine, as well.
3. Put the generated files in a `.jar` file, preserving the file structure.  I did this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281229/how-to-use-jaroutputstream-to-create-a-jar-file) as a template.  Examining the `.jar` file using [JarBrowser](http://jarbrowser.sourceforge.net/) showed that the file structure of the packages was preserved.  Using it, the Jar Catalog looks the same as a regular `.jar` file.  However, using JarBrowser, my jar doesn't show up under "CLASSPATH catalog."  This leads me to believe that my `.jar` file isn't being created correctly.
4. Load the `.jar` file into an instance of `URLClassLoader`.  I'm trying to load it using `Class.forName()` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Whenever I do step 4., I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky: I've already been to that question.  I'm using almost identical code but it's not working.  Hence different question :P

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime ?

Comment: I've tried `ClassLoader.loadClass`, as well.  Loading the class works whenever I use another jar someone else has made, just not my jar/package/class.

Comment: put the directory with compiled classes into classpath instead the jar file, and run your test program. If ClassNotFoundException still arise, error is in your classes or package structure, otherwise indeed in jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had a slash as a prefix to the file/directory names.  I was truncating the parent directory from the file name, but didn't take into account the trailing slash from the parent directory, so `/dir1/file1` was being done instead of `dir1/file1`.  I guess `JAR` files are picky.

Comment: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow
(click on this box to dismiss)"  I would have, sorry :/

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't realize there was a wait time. Just be sure to mark it as accepted when you can :)