# Generate jar from classes through java code - not commandline in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

How can I convert the commandline:

```
jar -cf myfile.jar *.class
```

to java code in Eclipse?

I hava all the classes pathes in the string. I need to generate jar at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use JarOutputStream to create a JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281229/how-to-use-jaroutputstream-to-create-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can create your command line and run it from java using either `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` or using `ProcessBuilder`.

Second, jar is just a zip file. You can create it using either `ZipOutputStream` or `JarOutputStream`