# javax.tools compiler generate jar

Tags: java, jar, java-compiler-api

currently i compile my java sourcefiles with:

```
ArrayList<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
String testpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path") + convertJarFilesToClassPath(getJarFiles());
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", testpath));
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-d", this.outputDir+"\\bin"));

ArrayList<File> files1 =  getSourceFiles();
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(files1);
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null ,fileManager ,null , optionList, null, compilationUnits );
boolean compiled = task.call();
```

Then i get my .class files correctly compiled, but i would like to have also a jar file generated.
I am not familiar with the JavaCompiler, i use jdk 7.

What do i have to do, to tell the javax.tools.JavaCompiler to generate a jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.tools.JavaCompiler` and `javac` only compile classes and generate `.class` files.

To bundle the compiled classes into a JAR file you can use `JarOutputStream`. Here is a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281295/3215527).