# Is there any way to programmatically compile a java project into a executable jar, on each run of the project within an IDE?

Tags: java, jar

I have a class, which has a main, which I'm trying to set as a VirtualMachine's agent.

I *could* extract it as a jar in eclipse, and add it to the build path, everyt time I change it, but that would be a drag.

this:

```
File f = new File("/FinalProject/src/finalproje/agent.java");
vm.loadAgent(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

fails to work.

Is there any way to either make this work, or programmatically compile the .jar file from agent.java?

Comment: what is *"extract it as a jar in eclipse*" supposed to mean? What have you tried, exactly? What is your actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You execute shell command from your java code. Then you can compile it to jar with a standard [command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). Take a look at this: [Execute Shell Code](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/)

Comment: This is usually done by using a build tool such as ant, maven or gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JarOutputStream`. I have used this before and it will work for what you are looking to do. Read this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281229/how-to-use-jaroutputstream-to-create-a-jar-file)

Good luck