# How to JAR files using relative path of root directory?

Tags: java, jar, compression

[How to use JarOutputStream to create a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281229/how-to-use-jaroutputstream-to-create-a-jar-file)

Using that solution causes creating entry with absolute path in *.jar file, for example c:/Users/foo/Temp/blah/com/example/Main.class. I want to build jar with path relative to root, in this example it will be c:/Users/foo/Temp/blah and entries should be com/example/... How to achieve that? Changing working directory is strongly platform-dependent, so it's not good solution.

PS. I've replaced Windows's backslash with slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'path' is actually whatever name you set into each `JarEntry` when creating it. Just calculate the relative path yourself and use that for the name parameter when calling the `JarEntry` constructor.