# Jar File - main class not found

Tags: java, jar, build, classpath, mainclass

So I have the following project Structure: 
I have a package called "com.github.liketechnik". My main class is Build in this package ("com.github.liketechnik.Build").

I programmatically put the compiled classes from there into a jar file with a correct manifest, e. g. containing a version attribute and a Main-Class entry "com.github.liketechnik.Build". The classes inside the jar are contained under "com/github/liketechnik/Build.class".

When running  `java -jar output.jar` it fails directly: "Error: Mainclass com.github.liketechnik.Build could not be found or loaded" (translated from german). When running the class directly via `java -cp build/main com.github.liketechnik.Build` (e. g. the class files directly, outside the jar), it works without proplems.

I tried this hours and also searched every single file for typos, so I appreciate any help with this problem as all other threads concerning such problems did not help with mine. If you need any more Information or the sourcecode directly I've no problems with giving this to you.

**EDIT:** Added structure of jar file.

The jar file has the following structure:

- one dir "META-INF" containing "MANIFEST.MF" with the mentioned entries.
- one dir structure "com/github/liketechnik/Build.class" (for example, contains other classes (in subpackages) too.

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.github.liketechnik.Build
```

Build.java:

```
package com.github.liketechnik;

public class Build {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Output when manually running: `Hi` (as expected)
Output when running from jar: `Fehler: Hauptklasse com.github.liketechnik.Build konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden` (Why?)

Comment: What does the structure of the JAR file look like? You can open it with any ZIP tool.

Comment: edited my answer showing the strucutre. I checked this file too, it seems correct too me.

Comment: Instead of describing the contents of files (such as the manifest), just **show** them by copy and pasting directly. You don't necessarily have to paste the entire thing, but showing relevant parts is much more helpful than an English description alone.

Comment: Also read [mcve]. You should provide the exact code that recreates the problem you are having so that anyone else can just copy and paste it to see for themselves.

Comment: Is it better like this? Or what should I append to this to make it easier to understand?

Comment: The code example is perfect. You could probably edit your question so that the entire thing reads more easily. You do not need to mark the edited parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like creating .jar archives programmatically is not as easy as it seems. It seems like beneath the .zip specifications  one needs to handle ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281295/8176420)) is another caveat, so the entries need to be added following the directory hierachy.

Example:
Assume you have directories `a` and `b`, `b` containing files `test.class` `toll.class`, you have to first add `a`, then `b` and then the files inside `b` . Otherwise it won't work.