# Testing custom Kafka Connect SMT using Test Containers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, testcontainers

I'm trying to use TestContainers to integration test a [Kafka Connect Custom SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html#custom-transform) (Simple Message Transformer) which needs to make use of a external library (e.g. Apache Commons).

The test should:

1. Spin up (a) Kafka, (b) ZooKeeper, (c) PostgreSQL database, (d) Kafka Connect containers using [TestContainers library](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/).
2. Connect instance should configure a [JDCB Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/overview.html) against the PostgreSQL database.
3. Integration test adds a row to a test database table.
4. JDBC Source Connector should detect the DB insert and create a Kafka message ...
5. ... and transform it using the custom SMT and post it to a Kafka topic.
6. The test reads the transformed message from topic and assert that the fields are correct.

The problem I am having is creating the JAR file which containing the custom SMT.

I found a blog article [Testing Kafka Connectors](https://www.morling.dev/blog/testing-kafka-connectors/) where the author creates a JAR file (containing a custom SMT) in a programatic way as part of the integration test as follows:

```java
    private static void createConnectorJar() throws IOException {
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
        JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("target/kcetcd-connector/etcd-connector.jar"), manifest);
        add(new File("target/classes"), target);
        target.close();
    }
```

*Ref: https://github.com/gunnarmorling/kcetcd/blob/main/src/test/java/dev/morling/kcetcd/source/EtcdConnectorIT.java*

This is then connected to the Docker TestContainer image as part of the integration test using the `withFileSystemBind` method to the jar file in the `classes/kcetcd-connector` folder:

```java
public static DebeziumContainer connectContainer = new DebeziumContainer("debezium/connect-base:1.9.5.Final")
            .withFileSystemBind("target/kcetcd-connector", "/kafka/connect/kcetcd-connector")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withKafka(kafkaContainer)
            .dependsOn(kafkaContainer);
```

However, this solution only works for simple SMTs which doesn't reply on external libraries (e.g. brought in using Gradle).  My test Kafka Connect container didn't successfully pick up the class in the JAR file.

Does anyone have a solution for testing a more complex SMT using test containers?  I think that the integration test essentially needs to create a shadow JAR bound to docker volume.

---

### Update (6 Oct 2023)

I've uploaded a working example to the following GitHub repo:

- [github.com/bobmarks/kafkakafka-connect-testcontainers-custom-smt](https://github.com/bobmarks/kafka-connect-testcontainers-custom-smt)

The code structure is as follows:

```
src
  main
    java
      smt
        test
          RandomField.java          Custom SMT which adds a field containing random characters

  test
    java
      smt
        test
          RandomFieldTest.java      Unit test to test RandomField
          SmtIntegrationTest.java   Integration test using TestContainers
```

The `SmtIntegrationTest` integration test class tries to do what I mentioned at the top (i.e. test everything end-to-end via actual Docker containers such as Kafka, ZooKeeper, SchemaRegistry, Postgres and KafkaConnect).

If you execute all the tests via `./gradlew test` ...

```
> Task :test
smt.test.SmtIntegrationTest

  Test db_insert_creates_kakfa_message_with_smt() FAILED
> :test > Executing test smt.test.SmtIntegrationTest
  java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
  Expected status code <201> but was <400>.
      at smt.test.SmtIntegrationTest.setupConnector(SmtIntegrationTest.java:352)

  Test db_insert_creates_kakfa_message() PASSED (1.3s)

smt.test.RandomFieldTest

  Test topLevelStructRequired() PASSED
  Test schemalessInsertRandomField() PASSED
  Test copySchemaAndInsertUuidField() PASSED

FAILURE: Executed 5 tests in 22.9s (1 failed)
```

... everything passes except for the `db_insert_creates_kakfa_message_with_smt` test method of integration test class `SmtIntegrationTest`.

The passing integration test method (`db_insert_creates_kakfa_message`) doesn't use a custom SMT, which proves that everything else works i.e. inserting a row into a database table is picked up correctly and results in a Kafka message being created and published to a Kakfa topic.

The only difference between the 2 tests is that when setting up the `JdbcSourceConnector` connector, the *failing test method* sets some transformer properties (e.g. `transforms=randomfield`) whereas the *passing method* doesn't. This is done via the `setupConnector` method as follows (note the `if` statement which toggles the transformer properties):

```java
    private void setupConnector(String databaseTable, String randomFieldName, int size, boolean useLetters, boolean useNumbers) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
        configMap.put("connector.class", "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector");
        configMap.put("tasks.max", "1");
        configMap.put("connection.url",
            format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:5432/%s?loggerLevel=OFF", POSTGRES_NETWORK_ALIAS, DB_NAME));
        configMap.put("connection.user", DB_USERNAME);
        configMap.put("connection.password", DB_PASSWORD);
        configMap.put("table.whitelist", databaseTable);
        configMap.put("mode", "timestamp+incrementing");
        configMap.put("validate.non.null", "false");
        configMap.put("topic.prefix", TOPIC_PREFIX + ".");
        configMap.put("timestamp.column.name", "updated");
        configMap.put("incrementing.column.name", "id");

        // Configure SMT if randomFieldName is set
        if (randomFieldName != null) {
            configMap.put("transforms", "randomfield");
            configMap.put("transforms.randomfield.type", "smt.test.RandomField$Value");
            configMap.put("transforms.randomfield.random.field.name", randomFieldName);
            configMap.put("transforms.randomfield.random.field.size", String.valueOf(size));
            configMap.put("transforms.randomfield.random.use.letters", String.valueOf(useLetters));
            configMap.put("transforms.randomfield.random.use.numbers", String.valueOf(useNumbers));
        }

        String payload = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(ImmutableMap.of(
            "name", CONNECTOR_NAME, "config", configMap));
        given()
            .log().headers()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(payload)
            .when()
            .post(getKafkaConnectUrl() + "/connectors")
            .andReturn()
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED);
    }
```

Examining the console output for the broken test shows: -

```
{
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
        Invalid value smt.test.RandomField$Value for configuration transforms.randomfield.type: Class smt.test.RandomField$Value could not be found.
        Invalid value null for configuration transforms.randomfield.type: Not a Transformation
        You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

The `Class smt.test.RandomField$Value could not be found` indicates that our custom transformer JAR file wasn't picked up.

While the `SmtIntegrationTest` test runs you can see all the running Docker containers by running `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps 

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                             PORTS                                         NAMES
670697d6f149   confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.5.0     "bash -c 'confluent-…"   12 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds (health: starting)   9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:58037->8083/tcp             connect-1fadc921-2a97-4b78-b325-de10c127c0ef
48982e55c008   confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.0             "/etc/confluent/dock…"   12 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds                      0.0.0.0:58027->9092/tcp                       blissful_shockley
62e194054ec4   confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.5.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   12 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds                      0.0.0.0:58031->8081/tcp                       blissful_dijkstra
bc54519a449d   postgres:11                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds                      0.0.0.0:58032->5432/tcp                       nifty_mestorf
b668c6def0a2   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0         "/etc/confluent/dock…"   12 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds                      2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:58035->2181/tcp   pensive_euler
8f2b26a2057a   testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1               "/bin/ryuk"              13 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds                      0.0.0.0:58028->8080/tcp                       testcontainers-ryuk-53dd0444-3f1f-499b-a555-c6d9eac11077
```

The integration test creates a JAR file containing the `RandomField` transformer class and binds it to the `/usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins` folder inside the *kafka-connect* container.

We can double check this JAR exists by running an `ls` command via a docker execute command:

```
$ docker exec $(docker ps | grep kafka-connect | cut -d " " -f1) ls -al /usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins 

total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Oct  6 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 appuser appuser 4096 Oct  6 12:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    5873 Oct  6 12:20 kafka-smt.jar
```

Next, if we check the *kafka-connect* container logs you'll see the following (timestamps removed for readability):

```
$ docker logs -f $(docker ps | grep kafka-connect | cut -d " " -f1)

...
INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/java/confluent-control-center (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
...
```

The first 2 lines shows Kafak Connect is scanning our custom folder `/usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins/`. The next 4 shows scanning one of the built-in Kafka Connect folders `/usr/share/java/confluent-control-center`.

Examining these logs it appears our custom folder doesn't register any plugins (due to the lack of `Added plugin` logs), whereas the `confluent-control-center` registers several plugins e.g. `org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector`.

My gut feeling is our custom SMT jar (created vi the `createConnectorPlugin` method) doesn't contain dependant libraries such as Apache Commons (which contains the `random()` method) but the logs don't show errors for this scenario.

Comment: SMT can easily be tested with unit  (which already exist in the jdbc connector repo) What behavior are you expecting to change with system testing?

Comment: I want to test at the integration level i.e. that the PostgreSQL source connector works against the configuration supplied to the custom SMT

Comment: I'm trying to understand how that would be a useful test, though? The SMT takes a Connect Struct, and produces another one... There doesn't need to be any Kafka or database interaction, as SMT are meant to be generic between any systems. Example - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/schema-registry-transfer-smt/blob/master/src/test/java/cricket/jmoore/kafka/connect/transforms/TransformTest.java#L484 ; the article you've found is about testing the whole connector itself therefore does need connections to etcd for example, not just the SMT

Comment: So I already have a unit test on the SMT which works well. This is to do an integration test to test everything at a higher level i.e. an update to a database will be correctly picked up and publish to a Kafka topic. The main reason for this integration test is to catch regressions at a higher level in e.g. changes to database tables / columns etc affecting the message on the Kafka topic or even updating the latest Kafka / Connect etc doesn't affect the integration of everything.

Comment: Your question was just about testing the SMT, though, which should generally not have any database interaction. Regardless, your question seems to really be about Gradle and file mounts to testcontainers... So, you should still be able to use `JarOutputStream` to copy the output of Gradle shadow jar plugin (i.e. an uber jar) which does contain your external dependencies, and copy those into a file mount. Otherwise, you can use Debezium Server in embedded mode rather than use a container for it, which simply takes your test classpath

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer here in the hope this is useful for others and thanks *@OneCricketeer* for your comments / help.

I've updated the test GitHub repo:

- [github.com/bobmarks/kafka-connect-testcontainers-custom-smt](https://github.com/bobmarks/kafka-connect-testcontainers-custom-smt)

... and if you do a gradle build both the unit and integration test  works:

```java
$ ./gradlew test

> Task :test

smt.test.SmtIntegrationTest

  Test db_insert_creates_kakfa_message_with_smt() PASSED (2s)
  Test db_insert_creates_kakfa_message() PASSED (6s)

smt.test.RandomFieldTest

  Test topLevelStructRequired() PASSED
  Test schemalessInsertRandomField() PASSED
  Test copySchemaAndInsertUuidField() PASSED

SUCCESS: Executed 5 tests in 1m 20s
```

@OneCricketeer mentioned:

> *So, you should still be able to use `JarOutputStream` to copy the output of Gradle shadow jar plugin (i.e. an uber jar) which does contain your external dependencies, and copy those into a file mount.*

However, I wasn't able to create an Uber JAR file using `JarOutputStream`. The solution I went with was to use Java and run `./gradlew shadowJar` as an external process (using Java `Runtime.exec(String command)` method) i.e.

```java
    public static File createConnectorPluginWithGradle() {
        // Check if file exists and delete if it does
        File existingJarFile = findFile("build/libs", "-all.jar");
        if (existingJarFile != null && existingJarFile.exists()) {
            existingJarFile.delete();
        }
        boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
        String gradleCmd = isWindows ? "gradlew.bat" : "./gradlew";
        String output = execCmd(gradleCmd + " shadowJar");
        if (output == null || !output.contains("BUILD SUCCESSFUL")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Gradle build unsuccessful\n\n" + output);
        }
        File jarFile = findFile("build/libs", "-all.jar");
        if (!jarFile.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Shadow jar does not exist: " + jarFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return jarFile;
    }
```

It deletes the JAR file (if already exists) and checks if running on a Windows vs Linux-type environment. It then either executes `gradlew.bat shadowJar` (Windows) or `./gradlew shadowJar` (other environments) via a `execCmd` method:

```java
    public static String execCmd(String cmd) {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
            return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error executing: " + cmd, ioEx);
        }
    }
```

The JAR file is returned as a `File` object which is then bound to the Kafka Connect docker container:

```java
    private static final String PLUGIN_JAR_FILE = "kafka-smt.jar";

    ...

    kafkaConnect.withFileSystemBind(jarFile.getAbsolutePath(),
            "/usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins/" + PLUGIN_JAR_FILE);
```

Now, if you refer back to the original question, when the Kafka Connect was parsing the `/usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins/` folder there was no `Added plugin ...` logs (which indicated that it couldn't succesfully load any SMT classes).

Now, if we examine the Kafka Connect logs as the `SmtIntegrationTest` runs we'll see (*timestamps / extra logs removed for readability*):

```
$ docker logs -f $(docker ps | grep kafka-connect | cut -d " " -f1)

...

INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/java/kafka-smt-plugins/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Added plugin 'smt.test.RandomField$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
INFO Added plugin 'smt.test.RandomField$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
...
INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/java/confluent-telemetry (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
```

The presense of the `Added plugin 'smt.test.RandomField$Value` log indicates our SMT class has been loaded succesfully and our integration test method ...

```java
    @Test
    public void db_insert_creates_kakfa_message_with_smt() throws Exception {
        String topicName = TOPIC_PREFIX + "." + DB_TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        setupConnector(DB_TABLE_EMPLOYEE, "my_random_field", 23, true, false);

        databaseInsert(DB_TABLE_EMPLOYEE, "id, name, manager", 1002, "John", "David");

        awaitForTopicCreation(topicName);
        List<ConsumerRecord> records = getRecordsFromKafkaTopic(topicName, 1);
        assertThat(records).hasSize(1);
        Map<String, Object> record = MAPPER.readValue((String) records.get(0).value(), Map.class);
        System.out.println(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(record));
        Map<String, Object> payload = (Map) record.get("payload");
        assertThat(payload).containsOnlyKeys("id", "name", "updated", "manager", "my_random_field")
            .containsEntry("id", 1002)
            .containsEntry("name", "John")
            .containsEntry("manager", "David");
        assertThat((String) payload.get("my_random_field")).matches("[a-zA-Z]{23}");
    }
```

... now passes successfully. Note, the `System.out.println` displays:

```json
{
  "payload" : {
    "id" : 1002,
    "name" : "John",
    "manager" : "David",
    "updated" : 1696930054712,
    "my_random_field" : "NpAmwjtwezVetpcNWKgzpbN"
  },
  "schema" : {
    "name" : "employee",
    "type" : "struct",
    "fields" : [ {
      "type" : "int32",
      "optional" : false,
      "field" : "id"
    }, {
      ...
    }, {
      "type" : "string",
      "optional" : false,
      "field" : "my_random_field"
    } ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `my_random_field` exists in both the `payload` and `schema` sections of the Kafka record which confirms our `RandomField` is working.