# Create a file of a given size and type in java

Tags: java, file, randomaccessfile

I'm using this code to generate a file of a given size in java:

```
File file = new File(basedir, filePath);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
raf.setLength(sizeInBytes);
raf.close();
```

I'm creating a .jar file, but the mime type is ***text/plain***(According to its magic header), and I need the file to be ***application/java-archive***. Is there any way for me to set the correct header for this RandomAccessFile?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to create a jar file manually instead of [using `java.util.jar.JarOutputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1281229/15880).

Comment: I need jar files of different contents for a stress test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally. The magic number for a jar file is (50 4b 03 04) [Taken from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))

```
File file = new File(basedir, filePath);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
raf.setLength(sizeInBytes);
byte[] magicHeader = new byte[4];
magicHeader[0] = 0x50;
magicHeader[1] = 0x4b;
magicHeader[2] = 0x03;
magicHeader[3] = 0x04;
raf.write(magicHeader, 0, 4);
raf.close();
```

Comment: Instead of `(byte)Integer.parseInt("50", 16)`, you can just write `0x50`. Same for the other hex numbers (look up "Java hex literals").